# How to implement a SAT solver for practice on kSAT?

Tags: algorithm, sat

There are a variety of SAT problems and solvers.

I see and use many offline and online SAT solvers for comparing and analysing different instances. For more than curiosity, I want to test different algorithms described in papers for kSAT.

How to implement a SAT solver like solvers based on DPLL by python, c++ or others? I am very interested in that.

The input format could be DIMACS-CNF, for example

1 -5 4 0

-1 5 3 4 0

represents the formula (x1 ∨ ¬x5 ∨ x4) ∧ (¬x1 ∨ x5 ∨ x3 ∨ x4).

Comment: There is plenty of documentation online (presentations, research papers, open source projects, etc.) about DPLL/CDCL SAT solvers. It is not clear from the question whether you consulted those sources and what *specific and practical* development problem did you encounter when implementing your own software. For instance, you could have started by forking [MiniSAT](http://minisat.se/), like many do. As it is, I am afraid that your question is *too broad* for this platform.

Comment: @Patrick Trentin Yeah... It is too broad, I will try! Thank you so much.